# How to use addchild in another class not the main class as of .fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to add to stage a movieclip in another class not the .as file as the same name of .fla file how can i get this.

When i run same code in main.as i get the result but in another class it runs but no result.

Comment: If you can post some piece of code then it would help us to help you... :)

Comment: <code>   var boardGraphics : MovieClip;
   boardGraphics = new MovieClip();
   boardGraphics.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
         boardGraphics.graphics.drawRect(10,10,10,10);
   boardGraphics.graphics.endFill();
   addChild(boardGraphics);
</code>

when i call this in my main class it works but in any other class it wont

Answer (score 1):

First add the *other* class to the stage using an addChild from the document class (main class). Now just call `this.addChild(whatever)` from the other class - it will work.

Adding the new child to self

```
Stage
|
|__DocumentClass - this.addChild(another_class)
   |
   | 
   |
   |__AnotherClass - this.addChild(new movieclip)
      |
      | 
      |
      |__ NewMovieClip
```

Adding the new child to the main movieclip

```
Stage
|
|__DocumentClass - this.addChild(another_class)
   |
   | 
   |
   |__AnotherClass - this.root.addChild(new movieclip)
   |
   | 
   |
   |__ NewMovieClip
```

Adding the new child to the stage

```
Stage
|
|__DocumentClass - this.addChild(another_class)
|  |
|  | 
|  |
|  |__AnotherClass - this.stage.addChild(new movieclip)
|
| 
|
|__ NewMovieClip
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to pass Stage object to the other class or make this other class a DisplayObject and add it to the Stage then stage object will be accessible to this class and you can add new DisplayObject to the stage.